# Why does this transistor circuit work?

Tags: transistors, circuit-design, pnp

In the following circuit, why does a certain amount of current flow into the transistor in the below circuit?

[image]

I can understand once the push-button switch is turned on, there would be current flowing through it:

[image]

But what does it flow in before then?

Comment: did you make note of the magnitude of current in the first circuit?

Comment: Did you notice that the sum of currents into the three terminals of the transistor do not equal zero? Typically if a number is small enough a simulator will treat it as zero. For this circuit, a few nano Amps can be ignored (just pretend it says 0).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The transistor is like all things in the real world...it is not perfect. Even when we expect that no current at all should be flowing there is a tiny leakage current. Note that the current flowing when the transistor is active is about 6,000,000 times greater than the leakage current. In most practical situations the leakage current is negligible.